# Does Icelandair Saga Premium have access to Fast Track at Stockholm Arlanda airport?

Tags: airports, airport-security, luxury, icelandair, arn

I'll be traveling in Saga Premium with Icelandair. Will I be able to use the Fast Track in Terminal 5 at Arlanda Airport in Stockholm, Sweden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Icelandair Saga Premium passengers are not allowed to use the Fast Track at Arlanda Airport.

Though, you may ask nicely and you might be able to take the Fast Track. But, you're not supposed to.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? Is it based on personal experience? P.S. Happy new year!

Comment: Personal experience. Asked the person at the check-in and I also read the sign at the Fast Track which didn't list Icelandair but several other airlines.